# How to get a $_POST from view module?

Tags: php, html, forms, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I want to get the checkboxes from a table in a view module, but I can't get it to work. Here's the table:

```
     <form action="" method="post">
     <TABLE id="dt_basic" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable">
        <THEAD>
          <TR>
            <TH></TH>
            <TH>ID</TH>
            <TH>Client</TH>
            <TH>User</TH>
            <TH>Role</TH>
            <TH>Projects</TH>
          </TR>
        </THEAD>
        <TBODY>
<?php
/* @var $item Admin\Model\User */
foreach ($this->users as $item) {
    ?>
    <TR>
        <TD class='admin'><input type="checkbox" name="users[]" value="<?php echo $item->id; ?>" class="users" checked/></TD>
        <TD class='admin c'><?= $item->id ?></TD>
        <TD class='admin'><?= $item->getClientObject() ?></TD>
        <TD class='admin'>
            <img src="<?= $item->getAvatarPath() ?>" alt="me" class="online avatar"/>
            <a title='details'
               href='/admin/user/detail/id/<?= $item->id ?>'><?= $item->name . " " . $item->surname ?> </a>
        </TD>
        <TD class='admin'><?= $item->getRoleObject() ?></TD>
        <TD class='admin'>
            <a title='projects' class='btn btn-default btn-sm'
               href='/admin/user/project/id/<?= $item->id ?>'><i
                    class='fa fa-icon-fix fa-briefcase'></i></a>
            <?
            foreach ($this->projects[$item->id] as $i => $project) {
                echo $project->getName();
                if ($i != sizeof($this->projects[$item->id]) - 1)
                    echo " • ";
            }
            ?>
        </TD>
    </TR>
<?php
}
?>
        </TBODY>
      </TABLE>
    </form>
```

I want to get the `users[]` array and use its elements inside the controller, but I can't find a way to get it, any suggestions?

Comment: give different and unique name to each field.

Answer (score 0):

You should to replace the row as follows:

```
<TD class='admin'><input type="checkbox" name="users[<?php echo $item->id; ?>]" class="users" checked/></TD>
```

In this way you'll receive the users where the keys are id-s, but values will be 'on'. You'll receive only checked users.

Regarding the question below:

```
if (!empty($_POST["users"])) {
    foreach (($_POST["users"]) as $selectedUsers=>$blabla) {
        $users = $this->getUserTable()->fetchAll(false, "id=" .  $selectedUsers);
    }
}
```

Comment: So after that I write this in the controller ?  
`if (!empty($_POST["users"])) {
                foreach (($_POST["users"]) as $selectedUsers) {
                    //Do something
                }`

Comment: I've added  - the code in my answer - $selectedUser have to be a key, not value - I've added corrected your code

Comment: It will be empty if you didn't checked anyone

Comment: print_r($_POST) and see what is coming

Comment: This is how it looks: http://i.imgur.com/f6NOwg0.png
I didn't set any action in the form, maybe that's the problem ?

Comment: Only `subject` and `message` appear as $_POST, no users.
Here's how the controller code looks now
            `if (!empty($_POST["users"])) {
                foreach (($_POST["users"]) as $selectedUsers=>$blabla) {
                    $users = $this->getUserTable()->fetchAll(false, "id=" .  $selectedUsers);
                }
            } else {
                $this->cache->error = "Please choose at least one user.";
                return $this->view;
            }`